# Show selected options first in bootstrap multi select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.3, bootstrap-4

This is my bootstrap multiselect "div". Now it's functioning properly.

My question is if user selected the value from the select box, Is there any chance to show the selected value first. Because I have more than 700+ Industry in my select box. So I want to show user selected Industry should display first.

For example: I want the **Acute Care** and **Acute Care-Outpatient** to display first.
[image: Image of multi-select]

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Industry<span class="notice-txt">*</span></p>
        <select name="industry[]" class="selectpicker selectpkrTrigger" multiple id="industry">
            <option value="" disabled >--Select--</option>
            @foreach($industrys as $in)
                <option value="{{$in['industrykey']}}" >{{$in['industry']}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no css solution to alter the order of the `<option>` items, however, with javascript it is possible to achieve what you want. Below is an example with sample values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#industry').on('change', function() {
        var note = $(this).find('option').first(),// the '--Select--' option
            selected = $(this).find('option:selected'),
            rest = $(this).find('option:not(:first-of-type):not(:selected)');
        
        var sorter = (a, b) => {
            let aName = a.innerText.toLowerCase(),
                bName = b.innerText.toLowerCase();
            return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
        };

        $(this)
            // adding '--Select--' 
            .html(note)
            // appending selected options sorted in alphabetical order
            .append(selected.sort(sorter))
            // adding the rest of the options sorted too
            .append(rest.sort(sorter));
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Industry<span class="notice-txt">*</span></p>
        <select id="industry" name="industry[]" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option value="" disabled >--Select--</option>
            <option value="01">A</option>
            <option value="02">B</option>
            <option value="03">C</option>
            <option value="04">D</option>
            <option value="05">E</option>
            <option value="06">F</option>
            <option value="07">G</option>
            <option value="08">H</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude for sharing your time for me. I just copy and paste this code. But it doesnt work in my case. Any other idea dude???

Comment: Is your form ajaxed or not present on initial pageload? I guess you have jQuery in place.

Comment: Yeah You are correct for my initial page load i used jquery. My form is not ajaxed

Comment: Any other idea or any thing to fix it

Comment: You could try with `$(document).on('change', '#industry', function() {` in the second line of the script. The snippet works in the answer, so it is something with the implementation on the site.

Comment: I am not sure but I think both bootstrap and jquery version are problem in my case

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this at the end? What was the problem?

Comment: No brother, Still looking for the answer, As Per your words i think its my sight problem because your snippet code functioning correctly. Anyway thanks alot brother for your care